# Android: ImageView height bounds due to some layout property

Tags: android, image, android-imageview, multi-touch, zooming

I am implementing multi-touch zoom to ImageView which got well but when I zoom it out, some part of image hides like goes behind of some view or due to some height restriction.

[image]

Layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bggray"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivapptitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="img"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/apptitle" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/titlecolor1">
      <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivdownloadedjpgfile"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"

            android:contentDescription="img"
            />                

    </ScrollView>    
</LinearLayout>
```

Class code

```
public class DownloadedImageDisplay extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

    private ImageView ivDownloadedImage;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.staffnotationtd);
        initializeVars();
        showImage();
        ivDownloadedImage.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    private void initializeVars()
    {
        ivDownloadedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivdownloadedjpgfile);
    }

    public void showImage()
    {
        String filePath;
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras == null) {
            filePath = null;
        } else {
            filePath= extras.getString("JPGFileName");
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
        ivDownloadedImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }


    //// Image Zooming code

    private static final String TAG = "Touch";
  //  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1f,MAX_ZOOM = 1f;

    // These matrices will be used to scale points of the image
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    // The 3 states (events) which the user is trying to perform
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // these PointF objects are used to record the point(s) the user is touching
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
        view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        float scale;

        dumpEvent(event);
        // Handle touch events here...

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) 
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   // first finger down only
                                                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                                                Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG"); // write to LogCat
                                                mode = DRAG;
                                                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted

                                                mode = NONE;
                                                Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                                                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // first and second finger down

                                                oldDist = spacing(event);
                                                Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
                                                if (oldDist > 5f) {
                                                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                                    midPoint(mid, event);
                                                    mode = ZOOM;
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
                                                }
                                                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                                                if (mode == DRAG) 
                                                { 
                                                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y); // create the transformation in the matrix  of points
                                                } 
                                                else if (mode == ZOOM) 
                                                { 
                                                    // pinch zooming
                                                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                                                    if (newDist > 5f) 
                                                    {
                                                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                                        scale = newDist / oldDist; // setting the scaling of the
                                                                                    // matrix...if scale > 1 means
                                                                                    // zoom in...if scale < 1 means
                                                                                    // zoom out
                                                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                break;
        }

        view.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen

        return true; // indicate event was handled
    }

    /*
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Method: spacing Parameters: MotionEvent Returns: float Description:
     * checks the spacing between the two fingers on touch
     * ----------------------------------------------------
     */

    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /*
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Method: midPoint Parameters: PointF object, MotionEvent Returns: void
     * Description: calculates the midpoint between the two fingers
     * ------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
    private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE","POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int action = event.getAction();
        int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);

        if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) 
        {
            sb.append("(pid ").append(action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
            sb.append(")");
        }

        sb.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) 
        {
            sb.append("#").append(i);
            sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
            sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
            sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
            if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                sb.append(";");
        }

        sb.append("]");
        Log.d("Touch Events ---------", sb.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it ... I just removed the Scroll view and it works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bggray"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivapptitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="img"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/apptitle" />
    </LinearLayout>

      <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivdownloadedjpgfile"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"

            android:contentDescription="img"
            />                

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point wrapping your ImageView in LinearLayout

I suspect the ImageView set it's height to wrap the original image and it will not be increased. Try using a fixed height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bggray"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivapptitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="img"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/apptitle" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/titlecolor1">

      <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivdownloadedjpgfile"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:contentDescription="img"/>                

    </ScrollView>    
</LinearLayout>
```